# Simple C# direction with declaring variables

Tags: c#

I just started trying to learn C#. I've read probably 50 tutorials so far and thought I had a good understanding. Apparently I was wrong. I've been doing a lot of reading on msdn.microsoft.com's C# Programmer's Reference but it's seeming to not be the best source for tutorials.

I'm literally trying to accomplish the most simplest of tasks. Trying to understand variables, manipulation, and inputs. I come from web programming and want to turn a PHP script into a desktop application so I'm trying to learn the basics of C# and I think I might need to learn a different language instead.

Basically, I have a textbox and a button. When the button is clicked, I want to check the text in the textbox and see if it matches a certain string. Then display a message box with a message.

```
private void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(txtCL.Text == "one") {
        bool myTest = true;
    } else {
        bool myTest = false;
    }
    if(myTest == true) {
        MessageBox.Show("You entered the correct password.", "Important Message");
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("The password you entered is not correct.", "Incorrect Input");
    }
}
```

Would really appreciate if someone could point me to better tutorials so I can learn quicker. Microsoft's documentation really hasn't taught me anything really.

I apologize for the stupid question, feel free to call me an idiot.

Comment: I do realize that I could not use the bool variable. But I'm trying to understand variables as well. How to declare them and use them in the code.

Comment: Check out some of these links: http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/csharp-fundamentals or http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL37FF167549C26150

Comment: basic rules of all the languages stays same, i.e. scope, variable instantiation, initialization and abv all logics. you're taking it too hard on yourself. if you were a php guy(a programmer), it should be easy for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a scoping issue, `myTest` does not exist, at least not *down there* - you're creating it each time within the scope of each of your initial conditions. If you do:

```
bool myTest = false;
if(txtCL.Text == "one") {
   myTest = true;
}
if(myTest == true) {
    MessageBox.Show("You entered the correct password.", "Important Message");
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("The password you entered is not correct.", "Incorrect Input");
}
```

Then you're specifying your boolean value, and setting it to false (which is the default value for a `bool` anyway, actually), then checking if your condition is met and reassigning it accordingly; it can then be evaluated to show your message box.

You could shorten this code yet more, an exercise for the reader. (:

Comment: +1, but please teach the additional lesson and suggest `bool myTest = (txtCL.Text == "one");` There's no need to use an `if` only to do either `myTest = true;` or `myTest = false`. (And of course `if (myTest == true)` can be abbreviated to `if (myTest)`, perhaps with a variable name change.)

Comment: Grant - Thank you very much. It makes sense now that you explained it.

stakx - I figured there was a way to do ternary statements, but haven't gotten to an example yet. Thank you as well.

Answer (score 3):

you don't really need a bool variable, you can make it simplier:

```
private void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(txtCL.Text == "one")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You entered the correct password.", "Important Message");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The password you entered is not correct.", "Incorrect Input");
    }
}
```

and if you need some tutorials, just google "C# beginner tutorials" or if you prefer video tutorials, you can take a look [here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAC325451207E3105).

Comment: At the time of my upvote, this was the only answer that pointed out what seems the most logical way of doing this.

Comment: I understand I don't NEED it. I'm trying to understand how to declare variables in different forms so when I get to building applications that require them, I know how. I addressed that in the comment under my question.

Comment: @Erick Hertlein, you are right, I accidentally didn't saw your comment, sorry.

Comment: Here's another stupid question. I use Visual Studio 2012. Most of the tutorials I come across are for command line programming, from what I gather. Would it be best to search for "C#.NET" to get application examples/tutorials or maybe "Visual C# beginner desktop tutorials"?

Comment: Try to google "c# windows forms tutorials" or better google what you are trying to make(for example "c# login tutorial"). There are also many video tutorials in youtube.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(...) {
        bool myTest = true;
    } else {
        bool myTest = false;
    }

    // At this point in time 'myTest' is not a known variable. 
    // It's out of scope already s your next line will cause a compile error.
    if(myTest == true) { 
        ...
    }
```

So you need to declare the variable in scope

```
    bool myTest = false;

    if(...) {
        myTest = true;
    } 

    // Now you can use the myTest variable
    if(myTest) { 
        ...
    }
```

As you already pointed out, you don't need the variable at all, since this would work all the same

```
private void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(txtCL.Text == "one") {
        MessageBox.Show("You entered the correct password.", "Important Message");
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("The password you entered is not correct.", "Incorrect Input");
    }
}
```

You can read as many books as you like, but since you already have programming experience with PHP I'd suggest to get more hands on experience with C#. In parallel a book of course does not hurt. But I think the approach you are following (reading online, coding stuff) will pay off in the end. Give it some time. Practice. A lot.

Answer (score -2):

i am assuming that nothing is happening when you click the button. is this true?  if it is, put a break point at the line: if(txtCL.Text == "one") , run the app and click it. If you do not hit the break point then there is no linkage between the 'click' event and your code. Explore the button properties and you will see a way to make the linkage.

stick with it, i was a PHP guy and now a C# guy. It can be done.